# Escaping semicolon and quotes in orientdb update operation

Tags: quotes, orientdb

I'm running into strange errors when trying to update strings with both semicolons and quotes.  For example, the following sql fails with the error:

> "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing closed string character: '"', position: 64:

`UPDATE #26:185 SET description = "<div style=\"text-align: right;\">Text</div>";`

However, if removed the ';', the sql works:

`UPDATE #26:185 SET description = "<div style=\"text-align: right\">Text</div>";`

Also, if remove the escaped quotes, but the leave the ';', the sql works:

`UPDATE #26:185 SET description = "Text;";`

Is this a core issue with orientdb or am I not properly escaping the string?

Comment: Hi Josh, which version of OrientDB are you using ?

Comment: Hi, should this `<div style="text-align: right;">Text</div>` the expected output ?

Comment: Yes, that is the expected output

Comment: We were using 2.1.1.  I put the wrong version in an earlier comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying your case with OrientDB 2.1.11 version

**STRUCTURE**:

```
create class MyClass extends V
create property MyClass.description string
create vertex MyClass set description = "Text"
```

**MyClass dataset**:

```
select from MyClass

----+-----+-------+-----------
#   |@RID |@CLASS |description
----+-----+-------+-----------
0   |#12:0|MyClass|Text
----+-----+-------+-----------
```

Now I update the record `#12:0` with your first update query:

```
UPDATE #12:0 SET description = "<div style=\"text-align: right;\">Text</div>";

Updated record(s) '1' in 0,032000 sec(s).
```

**Updated MyClass dataset**:

```
select from MyClass

----+-----+-------+------------------------------------------
#   |@RID |@CLASS |description
----+-----+-------+------------------------------------------
0   |#12:0|MyClass|<div style="text-align: right;">Text</div>
----+-----+-------+------------------------------------------
```

Probably the issue has been solved in the subsequent versions, could you try with the latest stable OrientDB version ?

Comment: Upgrading from 2.1.1 to 2.1.11 fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have tried with 2.1.2 and I haven't your exception

[image]

```
UPDATE #13:0 SET description = "<div style=\"text-align: right;\">Text</div>"
```

[image]

Hope it helps.